# lighttpd changing the root folder and the alias don't work

Tags: lighttpd

Following is my lighttpd.conf file
I changed the root folder and I declared an alias and both don't work.
/localhost/ is still "/var/www/html"

I also added a redirection for the C code
The ".c" redirection works OK.

```html
server.modules = (
 "mod_access",
 "mod_alias",
 "mod_compress",
  "mod_redirect",
            "mod_accesslog",
            "mod_fastcgi",
            "mod_rewrite",
            "mod_auth")

server.document-root        = "/usr/share/phpmyadmin"
server.upload-dirs          = ( "/var/cache/lighttpd/uploads" )
server.errorlog             = "/var/log/lighttpd/error.log"
server.pid-file             = "/var/run/lighttpd.pid"
server.username             = "www-data"
server.groupname            = "www-data"
server.port                 = 80

alias.url = ( "/phpmyadmin/" => "/usr/share/phpmyadmin/" )

fastcgi.debug = 1
fastcgi.server = (
    ".c" => (
    "echo.fcgi.handler" => (
        "socket" => "/tmp/cpp.fcgi.socket",
        "check-local" => "disable",
        "bin-path" => "/home/shlomo/cpp/echo.fcgi",
        "max-procs" => 1
    )
  )

)
index-file.names            = ( "index.php", "index.html", "index.lighttpd.html" )
url.access-deny             = ( "~", ".inc" )
static-file.exclude-extensions = ( ".php", ".pl", ".fcgi" )

compress.cache-dir          = "/var/cache/lighttpd/compress/"
compress.filetype           = ( "application/javascript", "text/css", "text/html", "text/plain" )

# default listening port for IPv6 falls back to the IPv4 port
## Use ipv6 if available
#include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/use-ipv6.pl " + server.port
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/create-mime.assign.pl"
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/include-conf-enabled.pl"
```